# Exclude a "user"

Tags: web

Last night a friend of mine came over. Over a nice cup of coffea we started an academic discussion of the Internet. Then he asked:

"I have a (theoretical)  website , `www.zzzz.yy` and somewhere in the cyberspace is a "user" called `annoying_user`, who fills the tables with spam. Excluding the fact, that the web-site code is badly coded, is it possible in some way to track his/her IP-number, his server-address, record this (file , database) and next time he/she (the annoying user) addresses my page (`www.zzzz.yy`), he/she  (and only he/she ) will be met by an excluding page (eg. HTTP 404), so I don't have to "clean" the tables each day, and how do I do that - if possible ? "

I could not give him a good answer - can anybody here ?  (REMEMBER ACADEMICAL QUESTION !)

Comment: Yes you can. How, depends totally on what you are using to server your website.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll tell him next time we "coffea" ...

Answer (score 0):

You can record the IP, but there are situations where the same IP is shared by tens or hundreds of people. Also, a malicious user will just use some free proxy to change his IP.

You could save a cookie on his machine and use that - but he might figure it out and just use private mode/clean cookies/use curl etc.

What you CAN do is require registration, make it at least partially inconvinient to create hundreds of new accounts (require email confirmation for example).

An interesting idea is used in Teamspeak - admin can set a minimum level of identity that users must present. That level is achieved by running an exponentially time-consuming cryptographic functions (users can do it from the application window). For example to get a lvl 5 identity you need a second or two. For level 20, it might take hours to generate.

If there is a problem with users switching identities, the admin can bump that level and legitimate users will just have to spend that time once - but a malicious user would have to spend those hours every time his identity is banned, basically limitting his effect :)

Comment: Thanks . I'll pass both answers to him next time we "coffea" ! ...  Thanks a lot.